# BrowserSync (Gulp Version) injecting new CSS changes but then reloads a cached CSS version in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, gulp, browser-sync

When i change my CSS files then BrowserSync injects the changes correctly but then Chrome reloads with the cached CSS file version.

It works in the newest Versions of Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome.

- browser-sync 2.17.5
- Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)
- macOS Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)

Here is my [gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d3f3a04e5b66fa82e2fc359bf0ba9861)

[image]

Comment: Use CTRL (Command) +F5 for reloading your browser tab (it should delete temporary files from browser cache).

Comment: When I force empty (Shift + CMD / CTRL + R) the cache then it works, but that is not the desire solution :-)

Comment: Well, then increment version of the css file created from gulp e.g. `style.css?v=2` ... But I dont work with Gulp, so I dont know how to make it automaticaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (workaround) is to:

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools, on Mac: Option + CMD + I
2. In the top right corner open **Settings** and under **Network** Disable cache [image: "Disable cache"]